# Combine dashboards to display in Home Page

Tags: dashboard

Can I combine 2 dashboards and display them in Home Page Components as shown below and this should be done in Lightning. The two dashboards here I'm trying to display are the custom dasboards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link .I don't think you can combine two dasboards
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212297&type=1

Comment: I need to do this in Lightning and the link says about classic. Updated my question as well.